# I want to use category as custom type in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

Generally, in WordPress when we click on any category, a page opens with all posts, associated with the category. I want to make a tweak in this behavior. I want when a category is clicked, all child-category should be listed and when a child-category gets clicked, all associated posts should be listed on the page.
I have no idea how to achieve this.
Could you guys give me any idea?
Regards!

Comment: Please update this question with information about the searches you've done here on SO. This seems like a common use case. If you find something similar to what you need, but not quite what you need, post the link(s) to the posts you found. Otherwise, it doesn't appear as though you've made any attempt to research the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to always show the categories, regardless of if they have posts, you could move the echoing of the '$category->name 'outside of the if '($posts)'. The way that it is currently, the category name will only be displayed if there is a post  with that category.

I think that a potential bigger challenge would be to display the categories in a hierarchy (indenting the sub-categories). If you simply move the display of the category name above the check for posts, they will all show as top-level categories. Here is a discussion of someone working on this issue on Stack Exchange:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270176/showing-categories-and-subcategories-with-posts

I wonder if another possibility would be to use: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/ and then override the HTML generation. It looks like that is what is happening here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98755/how-can-i-customize-the-wp-list-categories